# Do timed effects pause during in-game cutscenes?

Tags: diablo-iii

What happens to timed effects, such as the bonus from a shrine or a Monk's mantra, when an in-game cutscene plays (e.g. the cutscene which appears when you first encounter Deckard Cain)?

Does the timer pause while you're in the cutscene? Does it depend on whether other human players are connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up checking it myself, and the effects do not pause during in-game cutscenes, even when playing alone :(

Answer (score 1):

There was a post on battle.net forums suggesting that buffs did expire on cut-scenes. The actual post was removed.

[image]